# How to install Blur Admin on linux

Tags: node.js

While running blur-admin template locally using command $ gulp serve, it is giving error in chart.js and asking to install bower but it is already installed?

Comment: above warnings are generated in npm install while installing blur admin

Comment: So, you ran *npm install* inside blur admin directory?

Answer (score 0):

In **pages.module.js**,

Comment out these two lines.

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages', [
'ui.router',

'BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard',
'BlurAdmin.pages.ui',
'BlurAdmin.pages.components',
'BlurAdmin.pages.form',
// 'BlurAdmin.pages.tables',
// 'BlurAdmin.pages.charts',
.
.
.
.
```

These are the pages using chartjs.